# How to concatenation php array separated with comma

Tags: php

`$data=['test','test2'];`

I try with

`$finalData = implode(',',$data);`

Actual result

```
var_dump($finalData);
output : string(10) "test,test2"
```

Accepted result

```
var_dump('test1','test2');
output:  string(5) "test1" string(5) "test2"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. You're combining all the elements of the array into one string and later state that you want them separated. Can you please add some more clarification as to what you're trying to do here? Are you displaying these strings somewhere? If so, please show exactly what the output should look like. I doubt you want to use `var_dump` in actual code.

Comment: @El_Vanja I want to check in symfony role
here is a code like this 

$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_TEST')

Comment: If what you're really trying to do is check some roles, then your question should have been about checking multiple roles in Symfony, with an example of how you're currently trying to do it.

Comment: I think `$data` is already in the format you need.

Comment: @ChrisHaas It would be if it's Symfony 3.2.8 or higher. Which doesn't seem to be the case considering the use of `$securityContext`. The `SecurityContext` class has been deprecated in 2.6 and removed in 3. Additionally, this ability to pass an array of roles has been dropped in 5.

Comment: @BipedPhill You missed the point. The data is originally an array.

Comment: @El_Vanja Right you are. I have deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need **push array values** in function as **separated arguments**, you are probably searching for **Argument unpacking**

This can be done by **...** operator.

Used as

```
functionCall(...$array);
```